# How to implement generic ValidationBehavion using MediatR and FluentValidation so that the ValidationBehavion only triggers on commands

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cqrs, fluentvalidation, mediatr

I'm using CQRS and to separate commands and queries I created custom interfaces, so I want my ValidationBehavion to trigger only on the custom ICommand<TResponse> inheriting IRequest<TResponse>, and not in general on all IRequest<TResponse> requests.

To separate commands and queries I created custom interfaces:
(As an response value, I use the ErrorOr library. But I don't think it's worth getting into it, just keep in mind that there is always a response for both commands and quaries)

```cs
public interface ICommand<TResponse> 
    : IRequest<ErrorOr<TResponse>>
{ 
}

public interface IQuery<TResponse> 
    : IRequest<ErrorOr<TResponse>>
{
}
```

```cs
public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand, TResponse> 
    : IRequestHandler<TCommand, ErrorOr<TResponse>>
    where TCommand : ICommand<TResponse>
{
}

public interface IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResponse>
    : IRequestHandler<TQuery, ErrorOr<TResponse>>
    where TQuery : IQuery<TResponse>
{
}
```

I know of a standard approach where IPipelineBehavior is triggered to any requester and than we check if there is a validator for that requester or not:

```cs
public class ValidationBehavion<TRequest, TResponse>
    : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
    where TResponse : IErrorOr

{
    private readonly IValidator<TRequest>? _validator;

    public ValidationBehavion(IValidator<TRequest>? validator = null)
    {
        _validator = validator;
    }

    public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, 
    RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next, 
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if(_validator is null)
        {
            return await next();
        }

        var validationResult = await _validator.ValidateAsync(request);

        if (validationResult.IsValid)
        {
            return await next();
        }

        var validationErrors = validationResult.Errors
                .ConvertAll(error =>
                Errors.Wands.NotValid(
                    error.PropertyName,
                    error.ErrorMessage));

        return (dynamic)validationErrors;
    }
}
```

Since I have a separation between commands and queries, I thought I could specify ICommand<TResponse> instead of IRequest<TResponse> and redo the ValidationBehavion as follows:

```cs
public class ValidationBehavion<TRequest, TResponse>
    : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, ErrorOr<TResponse>>
    where TRequest : ICommand<TResponse>

{
    private readonly IValidator<TRequest> _validator;

    public ValidationBehavion(IValidator<TRequest> validator)
    {
        _validator = validator;
    }

    public async Task<ErrorOr<TResponse>> Handle(TRequest request, 
        RequestHandlerDelegate<ErrorOr<TResponse>> next, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var validationResult = await _validator.ValidateAsync(request);

        if (validationResult.IsValid)
        {
            return await next();
        }

        var validationErrors = validationResult.Errors
                .ConvertAll(error =>
                Errors.Wands.NotValid(
                    error.PropertyName,
                    error.ErrorMessage));

        return validationErrors;
    }
}
```

But then this IPipelineBehavior doesn't work at all and I have no idea why.